# Create Map using Javascript,Html from database

Tags: javascript, java, html

Does anyone know how to draw process map like this using javascript, html or java from database?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need to be a bit more specific in your question. What do you want to do with the diagram? Do you want to simply draw a diagram in a window? Do you want to create a .png with the diagram? A little more detail would help people point you in the right direction.

Comment: I wanna generate my dataset into diagram like this to see their order and relationship. Which activities follow which activities? My dataset like a process make a webpage and include many steps (A, B,C, D, E, F, G, H) and each step has start time and end time. For example A (03/04/2014-03/05/2015), B (03/06-03/07/2015)...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for some resources to draw network diagrams? If so, you can check vis.js (http://visjs.org/network_examples.html)

Sample Snippet below. Copy paste it to a file.html to see the result

```
<script src="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js"></script>
<link href="http://visjs.org/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="mynetwork"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
    var data = 
    { 
    dot: 'dinetwork {node[shape=box]; edge [length=350, color=gray, fontColor=black]; "State 1" -> "State 2" [label=154]; "State 1" -> "State 3" [label=62]; "State 3" -> "State 4" [label=100]; "State 1" -> "State 5" [label=32]; "State 4" -> "State 5" [label=170]; "State 1" [fontColor=white, color=red]"State 1" [shape=ellipse] }' 
    };
    var options = 
    { physics: { barnesHut: { gravitationalConstant: -10475, centralGravity: 0.1, springLength: 103, springConstant: 0.038, damping: 0.085 } }, smoothCurves: false };
    var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
    network.redraw();

    // resize the network when window resizes
    window.onresize = function () {
        network.redraw()
    };
</script>
```

Comment: S.Krishna!
Thank you for your reply. I am a new to javascript, java, html. So i don't know much detail. Here I wanna generate my dataset into diagram like this to see their order and relationship. Which activities follow which activities? My dataset like a process make a webpage and include many steps (A, B,C, D, E, F, G, H) and each step has start time and end time. For example A (03/04/2014-03/05/2015), B (03/06-03/07/2015)

Comment: @KevinBui vis.js has a lot of examples and you can pick and choose which fits. But the closest I could find was http://visjs.org/examples/network/data/dynamicData.html where you can give from and to states

Comment: S.Krishna, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KevinBui no problem. If this solves your question, please mark this as the answer